# ServiceStack HasPermission in the context of the request

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am trying to harness the authentication and authorisation features of servicestack so that I don't need to pollute my service code with this, which should lead to cleaner tests etc.

In my application, a user has permission to do something in a certain context.

ie A user can only view products that are in their product set.

To accomplish this I thought about decorating my productViewRequest dto with a permission attribute called canView and then to create my own implementation of IAuthSession to check that the user is requesting a product within their allowed set.

Would this be a decent approach or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Assuming it is a correct approach, how do I go about getting the context ie the productViewRequest object in the HasPermission call on my session implementation?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would check the ServiceStack built-in auth options https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization

If that doesn't fit your requirements, a request filter attribute will give you access to the request context.

```
public class CanViewAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute {
    private readonly string permission;

    public CanViewAttribute(string permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object responseDto) {
        // todo: check permission
    
        if (!hasPermission) {
          res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
          res.EndRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, spent some time on this and messing around with an attribute that inherited from RequiredPermissionAttribute instead of attempting my own request filter. That worked however the mvc integration doesn't execute the authorization attributes in the same way as ServiceStack core so I'm going to stop messing around and write a request filter as you have shown above. Thanks for the answer.